# How would I use grep to find all the words in a file that start with a-f

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Here is the code to look for all the words in a file starting with a. What about words that start with a-f?

```
grep -E '\ba' data.txt
```

Comment: `grep -Ei '\b[a-f]\w*'`

Comment: That will find all the *lines* that *contain* such a word. Add the `-o` option for the actual words.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question may be quite ambiguous, I will try to add all the possible solutions I can find for it. Let's start with a sample file, in my case containing the following words so I can explain myself better:

```
ascii
affair
a-f-f-i-l-i-a-t-e
barcode
break
charset
character
delete
draft
execute
example
force
failure
grip
group
halt
held
inode
instance
joke
jekyll
```

That said, if you want to `grep` all the words starting with the letters that go from a to f (this is, every word starting by a, b, c, d, e **and** f) you would use:

```
grep -E "^[a-f]" data.txt
```

And the output you would see is this one:

```
ascii
affair
barcode
break
charset
character
delete
draft
execute
example
force
failure
```

Now, if you want to filter the words starting literally by the string `a-f` for some reason then you would use this:

```
grep -E "^a-f" data.txt
```

And you would see that the output would look like this:

```
a-f-f-i-l-i-a-t-e
```

In this case the key is not that much `grep` knowledge but [regex stuff](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html).

Hope you find it useful.